# How to store temporary cart data in cache using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, n-tier-architecture

I am doing project using N-Tier Architecture with ADO.NET and MVC
but don't know how to perform caching

Kindly suggest me some way's please

### **Here it is my temperory data appended in cart :**

```
var cartdata = '<li id="product-item">' +
                     '<img id="ud-product-image1" src=' + data["FilePath"] + data["FileName"] + ' alt="">' +
                               '<a hidden id="ud-product-image">' + data["FilePath"] + data["FileName"] + '</a>' +
                                '<button onclick="return Removepart();" id="btnclose" type="button" class="close">×</button>' +
                                '<div class="overflow-h">' +
                                    '<span id="ud-product-name">' + data["Name"] + '</span>' +
                                    '<small id="ud-cart-product-price">1 x $' + data["MRP"] + '</small>' +
                                '</div>' +
                    '</li>';
                    $("#mCSB_1_container").append(cartdata);
```

---

### Here it is  part where every time

part will append ::::

```
 <div class="shop-badge badge-icons pull-right">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                    <span id="countitem" class="badge badge-sea rounded-x"><div id="counter">0</div></span>

                    <div class="badge-open">
                        <ul id="total-item" class="list-unstyled mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="minimal-dark">
                            <div id="Empty-Cart-Image">
                                <img src="~/Contents/img/empty_cart.jpg" style="height:150px;width:320px;" />
                            </div>

                            <!--// Actual Shopping Item Loaded here -->
                            <!-- Each time <li> portion will be added-->
                        </ul>
                        <div class="subtotal">
                            <div class="overflow-h margin-bottom-10">
                                <span>Subtotal</span>
                                <span class="pull-right subtotal-cost">$1200.00</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="shop-ui-inner.html" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-sea-shop btn-block">View Cart</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="shop-ui-add-to-cart.html" class="btn-u btn-u-sea-shop btn-block">Checkout</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So temporary cart item will be added but problem is that when page being refreshed , data will be lost

Comment: Think about where you want to store the data. In a cookie, in the database etc. Then wire it up.

Answer (score 0):

You may get opinions on this question more than facts, so here is my implementation for my shopping cart applications.

I normally create ***ShoppingCart table in database***. Then save Id of the shopping cart inside cookie on the client browser. *Note: I prefer **GUID** for ShoppingCart Id so that malicious user won't able to guess other carts easily.*

In addition, if user logins, I also save the UserId in the same table, so user can still view his/her shopping cart at any computer like amazon.com.

After user checkout successfully, I then move items from *ShoppingCart* table to ***Order*** and ***OrderItem*** tables and clear the cart.

If you do not want above approach, you can also store in ***Session State***. Draw-back of using Session State is, if customer closes the browser accidentally, App Domain restart, or App Pool recycle, s/he will have to start all over again.

Comment: Personally, I go with the cookie approach as well, at least for anonymous carts. Carts belonging to authenticated users are tied to their user accounts. However, the reasons for discouraging session use are only applicable if you're using In Proc sessions. If you have a persistent backing like SQL Server, those are not issues.

Comment: I forgot to mentions about [InProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) mode only. It should not be issue in StateServer, SQLServer and Custom like Redis Cache. Thank Chris for pointing out.

Comment: The only reason I don't store cart info in sessions is because sessions generally have a relatively quick timeout (20 minutes by default). Where as I can independently set a cookie with a cart identifier for 2 weeks or more, allowing a far more persistent-style cart. Also, using GUIDs are a good step, but users could still fudge around with GUIDs to try to find other carts. It'd be harder than an int, but not impossible. You should still encrypt the cookie data and, of course, use SSL with the Secure flag on your cookie.

Comment: Totally agreed with you but can you show how to use cache[] inside that

Comment: @ManavPandya You cannot use Cache to store user specific data, because same cache can be shared cross all users.